# What does {23.0231*213.759}${23.0231*213.759}{{=23.0231*213.759}} mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, logfile

I was going through the API logs of a Ruby on Rails app, and I noticed this input on a few failed calls. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Why tag `math` and `numbers` but no tags involving ruby on rails and/or whatever API you are using? Your question doesn't have a mathematical answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what they mean. I assumed it might be a formula. I changed the tags as requested.

Comment: It is a reasonable guess, but dollar signs have no standard meaning in mathematics and in the context of ruby on rails, something like `213.759` makes me think of part of an IP address rather than a floating point number between 213 and 214.

Comment: I've seen `{{= ... }}` used in some JavaScript template systems to avoid conflicts with `<%= ... %>`. Perhaps you just have a broken client app.

Comment: like @muistooshort mentioned `{{ ... }}` syntax is used by handlebars, mustache, angular, etc. as a and `${` is a javascript template literal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals